# How to write a correct trigger with a subquery which is returning more than one value

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I need to create a trigger that instead of inserting in a view a row inserts the values in 3 tables.
This is the correct trigger:

```
 INSTEAD OF INSERT ON Retete_vegetariane
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO categorie(categ_id, tip)
    VALUES(:NEW.categ_id, :NEW.tip);

    INSERT INTO Ingredient(ingred_id, ingredient)
    VALUES(:NEW.ingred_id, :NEW.ingredient);

    INSERT INTO Reteta(reteta_id, nume, descriere, categ_id, vegetariana, timp_preparare, portii)
    VALUES(:NEW.reteta_id, :NEW.reteta, :NEW.descriere, :NEW.categ_id,'D', :NEW.timp_preparare, :NEW.portii);
    
    INSERT INTO Set_Ingrediente(reteta_id, ingred_id, cantitate, um, comentarii)
    VALUES (:NEW.reteta_id, :NEW.ingred_id, :NEW.cantitate, :NEW.um, :NEW.comentarii);
END;
/
```

Now I want to update a trigger to raise an application error if the reteta_id already exists. It still was raising an error saying that reteta_id is a primary key, but now I want it to say that it already exists.
This is the code that i tried but it says that you cant use a subquery like this in a trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ad_vegetarian
 INSTEAD OF INSERT ON Retete_vegetariane
 FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
 variabil reteta.reteta_id%type;
BEGIN
variabil:=:NEW.reteta_id;
 IF variabil EXISTS(
    SELECT DISTINCT reteta_id FROM reteta;) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20512,'Reteta_id  already exists');
END IF;
    INSERT INTO categorie(categ_id, tip)
    VALUES(:NEW.categ_id, :NEW.tip);
    INSERT INTO Ingredient(ingred_id, ingredient)
    VALUES(:NEW.ingred_id, :NEW.ingredient);
    INSERT INTO Reteta(reteta_id, nume, descriere, categ_id, vegetariana, timp_preparare, portii)
    VALUES(:NEW.reteta_id, :NEW.reteta, :NEW.descriere, :NEW.categ_id,'D', :NEW.timp_preparare, :NEW.portii);
    INSERT INTO Set_Ingrediente(reteta_id, ingred_id, cantitate, um, comentarii)
    VALUES (:NEW.reteta_id, :NEW.ingred_id, :NEW.cantitate, :NEW.um, :NEW.comentarii);
END;/
```

Comment: I want to mention that I just started working with SQL (learn to program as well) and I don't have any examples so anything can help. If someone wants the tables I can post them.

Comment: Handle `dup_val_on_index` exception and raise your custom exception. Instead of read/write you'd better to perform write and notify if it fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move subquery out of `IF`:

```
...
begin
  select nvl(max(1), 0)
  into variabil
  from dual 
  where exists (select null
                from reteta
                where reteta_id = :new.reteta_id
               );

  if variabil = 1 then
     raise_application_error(-20512, 'Reteta_id already exists');
  end if;  
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you it's working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation for [`IF`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/IF-statement.html#GUID-B7D65A8E-B0C3-448F-B79C-6C330190A266), you'll find that it accepts `boolean_expression` after `IF`. [`boolean_expression`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/expression.html#GUID-D4700B45-F2C8-443E-AEE7-2BD20FFD45B8) definition lists these alternatives in `conditional_predicate` branch:

```
{ collection.EXISTS ( index )
| expression { IS [ NOT ] NULL
             | [ NOT ] { BETWEEN expression AND expression
                       | IN ( expression [, expression ]... )
                       | LIKE pattern
                       }
             | relational_operator expression
             }
| { named_cursor | SQL } % { FOUND | ISOPEN | NOTFOUND }
}
```

It doesn't allow you to put `EXISTS` predicate, because it is a SQL predicate.

You may avoid double check (on select and on subsequent insert) of existence: perform `insert` and handle `dup_val_on_index` exception.

> ```
> create table t1 (
>   id1 int primary key,
>   val1 varchar2(100)
> )
> ```

> ```
> create table t2 (
>   id2 int primary key,
>   val2 varchar2(100),
>   id1 references t1(id1)
> )
> ```

> ```
> create view v_test as
> select *
> from t1
>   join t2
>   using(id1)
> ```

> ```
> create trigger trg_test
> instead of insert on v_test
> for each row
> begin
>   insert into t1(id1, val1)
>   values (:new.id1, :new.val1);
>   
>   begin
>     insert into t2(id2, val2, id1)
>     values(:new.id2, :new.val2, :new.id1);
>   exception
>     when dup_val_on_index then
>       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20512,'Reteta_id  already exists');
>   end;
> end;
> /
> ```

> ```
> insert into v_test(id1, val1, id2, val2)
> values(1, 'A', 1, 'B')
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> insert into v_test(id1, val1, id2, val2)
> values(2, 'AA', 1, 'B')
> ```
>
> ```
> ORA-20512: Reteta_id  already exists
> ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_CPKPBNEZVLNFZLUOGPNZ.TRG_TEST", line 10
> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FIDDLE_CPKPBNEZVLNFZLUOGPNZ.TRG_TEST'
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=043ec058139678085819c6e5de9b9e1a)*